# htaccess Redirect 301 : mysite.com/sub/ to mysite.com/sub/home

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

my homepage `url` is like this `http://mysite.com/sub/`

I just want it to redirect to new `url` something like this `http://mysite.com/sub/home?lang=en`

here's my `code`

`Redirect 301 /sub/ /sub/home?lang=en`

Problem/error:

the new `url` becomes like this `http://mysite.com/sub/home?lang=enhome`

there's unnecessary `home` concatinated after `en`

how can I removed this? Or is there something wrong with my code?

don't know there's might be already same question like this

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Redirect` directive "connects" 2 path nodes, and you've got one inside the other (`/sub/home` is *inside* `/sub`). For example, if the directive looks like this:

Redirect 301 /a /b

This means when someone requests `http://mysite.com/a/foo/bar` they get redirected to `http://mysite.com/b/foo/bar`. What happens when you get redirected to `/sub/home` is that you get redirected *again* because `/sub/home` matches the pattern `/sub`, and the `home` gets appended, thus `/sub/home?lang=enhome`.

You can try using `RedirectMatch` instead, which doesn't "connect" path nodes:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub/?$ /sub/home?lang=en
```

Or mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?sub/?$ /sub/home?lang=en [L,R=301,QSA]
```